# Gem path used by rake different than system path on OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, rake, rubygems

```
> gem env gempath
/Users/davec/.gem/ruby/1.8:/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

> head Rakefile
require 'rubygems'
puts Gem.path
require 'rake/clean'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rcov'
require 'rcov/rcovtask'

> rake
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- rcov
/Users/davec/Projects/matrix/rakefile:5
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

If I go into irb, or create a `.rb` script, I can require gems that I've installed.

I have the latest `rubygems-update`, `rake`, and `rcov`.

Anyone seen this before?  It seems like something is amiss and I'd like to avoid setting `GEM_PATH` or hacking `/etc/gemrc` (which doesn't exist at the moment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/opt/local/lib is generally the path configured by macports.
Did you install RubyGems via macports?

Also ensure `which gem` doesn't return the /opt/local path.

If so, I would suggest to remove any macports ruby package and install RubyGems from source.
Also, Leopard should come with RubyGems installed (AFAIK).

Comment: I've got mine in /usr/bin/gem, that is a symbolic link to /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/gem

Comment: uninstall gem from port and re-symlinked the above path to `/usr/bin/gem` and all is good.