# Ruby gems install vs. runtime path on OSX

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, rvm, open4

**Where's the mismatch between gem install path and used Rakefile path?**

I originally wanted to run a Rakefile on my Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.4.
That failed on a missing 'open4' package.

I have no experience with ruby and little with Mac, but I googled open4 and found:

```
gem install open4
```

That also failed, but with sudo it succeeded.

It still didn't work though and my conclusion is that the install path:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
```

is different from the runtime include path, which I dumped from the script:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/powerpc-darwin12.0
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/universal-darwin12.0
/Library/Ruby/Site
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/powerpc-darwin12.0
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0
```

More googling led me to stackoverflow [understanding-rubys-load-paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671318/understanding-rubys-load-paths) and [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548809/pg-gem-install-on-mac-os-lion-with-rvm).
They all seem to conclude the solution is [RVM](http://rvm.io/) (links to RVM were broken)

I installed that:

```
sudo curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

But the path used by RVM was no better:

```
$ rvm gemdir
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
```

A [very old question - gem-path-used-by-rake-different-than-system-path-on-os-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064065/gem-path-used-by-rake-different-than-system-path-on-os-x) seems to cover what I want to know, but the solution doesn't seem relevant on current OSX

Where's the mismatch between install and used path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use an rvm ruby:

```
rvm use ruby --install --default
```

Comment: Thx. That did the trick, together with 'rvm all do gem install open4'.
I still don't get why the cumbersome package + version management is necessary, but then I may not need to know.
Thanks again :-)

Comment: after `use` it should be enough to `gem install open4` doing it for `all` is not the proper way.